# How do I identify Sys.UI._Timer in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

In my web page source code I have:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.UI._Timer, {"enabled":true,"interval":300000,"uniqueID":"timerMain"}, null, null, $get("timerMain"));
});
```

What is Sys.UI._Timer ? Is it a .Net class on the server side?

Comment: You need to add more information. I'm guessing you are using .Net framework, then you should include the .Net tag, so those devs can see. As people outside of this framework will not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sys.UI._Timer` is a class which resembles [`System.Web.UI.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) server control but runs in client-side (using JS) which creates timer control using AJAX client library. The default constructor definition of that class is shown below:

```
Sys.UI._Timer = function Sys$UI$_Timer(element) { 
   Sys.UI._Timer.initializeBase(this,[element]); 

   this._interval = 60000; // Interval property, measured in milliseconds
   this._enabled = true;   // Enabled property 
   this._uniqueID = null; // UniqueID property

   // client-side only properties
   this._postbackPending = false; 
   this._raiseTickDelegate = null; 
   this._endRequestHandlerDelegate = null; 
   this._timer = null; 
   this._pageRequestManager = null;
}
```

Note that [`$create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb397487%28v%3Dvs.140%29) is shorthand from [`Sys.Component.create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb310863(v=vs.140)) static method, which creates (and also initializes) a component with specified type as parameter (in this case, `Sys.UI._Timer`). The property values you want to set into component properties must be provided in JSON format and property names usage are given without underscores (hence `_interval` becomes just `interval`), using this syntax:

```
$create(type, { "propertyName": value, ... }, events, references, $get(elementName));
```

Further reading:

[Sys.UI._Timer - ASP.NET AJAX Client Library](http://www.infinitezest.com/SourceViewer/AJAXSourceMethods.aspx?Class=_Timer)

[Sys.UI Namespace - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb397431(v=vs.140))